# Why am I getting Illegal Number of Operator Errors for these assembly Instructions?

Tags: c++, assembly

I have a C++ project where I use various bits of assembly code.

My project wont compile with the following lines, it says "Illegal number of operands". How can I fix this?

These are examples of the lines that are causing the issues...

```
__asm
{
    FST DWORD PTR SS : [ESP + 0x0C] , ST(0)
    FSTP DWORD PTR SS : [ESP + 0x08] , ST(0)
    FILD ST(0), DWORD PTR SS : [ESP + 0x98]
}
```

Comment: Looks like more than one instruction in the `__asm` block. Suggestion: Try to remove as much as possible and note when the error vanishes. Then, identify the required syntax for that one instruction.

Comment: I've done that, the above lines are just example of individual lines that all cause the issue... It's anytime I use the FST/FSTP/FILD instructions. @harper

Comment: According to `https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Floating_Point#Examples` the `ST(0)` is implicit and must not be written. At least the first hit for "assembler x86 floating point" shows this.

Comment: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fst:fstp is a scrape of Intel's PDF, confirming that in standard Intel syntax (like MSVC uses) x87 load/store instructions take one operand.  Also http://www.ray.masmcode.com/tutorial/ is a good x87 tutorial.  BTW, inline asm normally shouldn't be using numeric offsets relative to ESP, use C variable names.  (Unless you're in a `naked` function, in which case it's like writing in a separate .asm file, where you need your own `ret` instruction too.)